# Best way to duplicate an huge Amazon Aurora 2 (MySQL 5.7) DB into an Amazon Aurora 3 (MySQL 8.0)?

Tags: backup, mysql-5.7, mysqldump, aws, aws-aurora

I would like to upgrade to Amazon Aurora 3 (MySQL 8.0) an Amazon Aurora 2 (MySQL 5.7).
In-place upgrade isn't available, Snapshot upgrade isn't possible neither because the production machine has the backtrack feature used previously...

I perform some research about tools available (mysqldump, mydumper, XtraBackup), and conclude that mysqldump is too slow, mydumper seems to works, but I can't predict exactly how much time it will take, XtraBackup can't work because Aurora is a managed service and it can't perform some magic at the cluster level.

As Amazon Aurora came with some "bonus features", I think about using LOAD FROM S3 / EXPORT INTO S3, as I know it's pretty fast, I export in only some hours into S3 all my structures and datas.

I perform some split by size of the files, and get with thousands of files in S3, then I start loading it 2~3 parallel clients, in different tables, with `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; SET unique_checks=0; SET sql_log_bin=0;` in front of each queries. Targeting files (as loading using prefix seems to increase too much the CPU usages)

I could probably try to perform some additional tricks, finding the perfect chunk-size for S3 files to load, ..., but I would like to know if there could be specific mysql parameters/settings that can be used with AWS Aurora to increase the loading speed.

The DB size is around 2TB, some tables are partitioned (I load each partition in a different file for now)
I expect my script to take ~28 hours for the import step with the default settings for a memory optimized instance sized 2xlarge... Maybe increase the instance size can also help during the process... (or allow me to parallelize more).

Could I have some advices?

Comment: Have you considered using replication?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the binlog replication would only allow me to synchronize changes from production to my mysql8 instance, but not sync the previous data.


But this is not necessarily necessary in my case (I can leave my production in "read only" for about 48h, and process all the 48h writing load afterwards), which will be in my case maybe simpler since there are big daily deletions mixed to my inserts.